# Removing all records in many-to-many table after removing parent item using Nhibernate

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

please help me resolve following situation. I have three tables Cardlist, Contact and many-to-many table ContactCardlist. I want to remove all records in many-to-many table ContactCardlist on removing of record in Cardlist. So, I find the required Cardlist, use foreach to iterate by "contactcardlists"-set and use session.Delete(ItemFromTheSet) to remove each record. But after transaction.commit() I obtain an exception which says that we can not update column CardlistId(in table ContactCardlist) with NULL. So "Update" command is used, instead of "Delete" one.

Below you can find mapping for tables Cardlist and ContactCardlist.

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="XXXXX.Entities" assembly="XXXXX">
  <class name="ContactCardlist" table="ContactCardlist">
    <composite-id class="ContactsCardlistId" name="ContactsCardlistId" unsaved-value="any" >
      <key-many-to-one name="cardlist" class="Cardlist"  column="CardlistId" />
      <key-many-to-one name="contact" class="Contact"  column="ContactId" />
    </composite-id>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="XXXXXXXXX.Entities" assembly="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
    <class name="Cardlist" table="Cardlist">
        <id name="cardlistid" column="cardlistid" type="int">
            <generator  class="native"/>
        </id>
        ....//lots of properties

    <set name = "contactcardlists" cascade="none"  order-by="ContactId">
      <key column ="cardlistid"/>
      <one-to-many class="ContactCardlist" />
    </set>    
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are experiencing is coming from the NHibernate ISession nature.

1. We do load the "parent" `Cardlist`, so the current `session` knows about this object, and even about its children
2. We iterate over the children and ask the `session.Delete(child)` *(ItemFromTheSet)*
3. Finally `session.Flush()` is called, and NHibernates must decide which SQL Statements must be executed
4. All the *children*, mapped to the *parent*, are about to be deleted. From the mapping above, NHibernate understands, that they must be firstly removed from the `<set name = "contactcardlists">` collection.
5. The Updates, are issued, chaning the parent `<key column ="cardlistid"/>` to be null

So, that is what happened. How can we solve it? First of all, we have to inform NHibernate, that the child is fully aware about its parent, and can manage itself. That is the `inverse="true"` setting

```
<set name = "contactcardlists" inverse="true"
     cascade="none"  order-by="ContactId">
  <key column ="cardlistid"/>
  <one-to-many class="ContactCardlist" />
</set>
```

This will instruct NHibernate to directly handle child, and issue DELETE statement only.

The cascading could be next improvement. Because that will allow us to call

```
parent.contactcardlists.Clear()
session.Udpate(parent)
```

and NHibernate will correclty issue DELETE statements. Mapping in that case should be like:

```
<set name = "contactcardlists" inverse="true"
     cascade="all-delete-orphan"  
     order-by="ContactId">
  <key column ="cardlistid"/>
  <one-to-many class="ContactCardlist" />
</set>
```

Finally, if you can introduce the Surrogated key into the pairing table ContactCardlist - ContactCardlistId, lot of stuff would be simplified. Really a lot. The mapping of the child then could be:

```
<class name="ContactCardlist" table="ContactCardlist">
  <id column="ContactsCardlistId" name="Id" />

  <many-to-one name="cardlist" class="Cardlist" column="CardlistId" />
  <many-to-one name="contact"  class="Contact"  column="ContactId" />

</class>
```

And working with an object, which does have the Surrogated key... is much more easier

Comment: Sorry for additional question: as I understand we can just add inverse="true" to the set's description and use Delete method in the foreach statement(without changing of property "cascade" from "None" to "all-delete-orphan")? You said "next improvement", so as I understand it is not a mandatory change.

Comment: The inverse="true" *(and you should google it for sure, to get more info, please)* means: NHibernate, this collection is built from elements, who are able to take care about themselves. If everything is properly set, it means, that once this Item is removed from collection, NHibernate directly communicate with this item: to DELETE. Without inverse... NHibernate can not be sure, and must do UPDATE first... to remove the reference from child, and then DELETE...

Comment: Great if that helped. Enjoy NHibernate... it is an awesome tool ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with NHibernate, but have you considered either:

(a) setting up a cascading relationship for OnDelete between CardList and ContactCardlist (if possible) and setting an index on the foreign key in ContactCardlist to ensure efficiency.

OR

(b) using raw ADO to remove the records with a "DELETE FROM ContactCardlist WHERE Cardlistid = X".

Option (a) is simple and effective.  Option (b) is much more efficient than item iteration.

Either would work, but option (a) ensures related relationships are always removed without any further work.